# No puedo validar con new Date

Tags: javascript, date

sucede que quiero validar si una fecha es 24 de diciembre de cualquier año, lo intente hacer y en la consola me dice que es la misma fecha, sin embargo al probar en la condición me dice que es falso. Alguien sabe por que sucede?

```
function timeForMilkAndCookies(date) {
 var anyo = date.getFullYear()
 var f1 = new Date(anyo, 11, 24); 
 if (date === f1){
   return console.log(true)
 }else{
   return console.log(false)
 }
}

timeForMilkAndCookies(new Date(3000,11,24))
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no pruebas con `date.getDate() === 24 && date.getMonth() === 11`? La condición `date === f1` te da `false` porque `f1` y `date` son dos instancias de `Date` diferentes. No evalúa su valor.

Comment: El problema es que estas comparando "2021-11-24 y 3000-11-24", esas fechas no son iguales, lo que harias es solamente comprar `mes y dia` para obtener lo que quieres